# Pass value from a href inside a bootstrap modal using php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, href

I have a link like this.

```
<a value-id='1' href='#myModal' class='marker' title='Edit'>LINK</a>
```

Inside the modal i would like to receive the value in php.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <?php
                //CODE TO PUT THE VALUE INSIDE A VARIABLE
            ?>    

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how to put the value inside the variable...

Comment: you may try <?=$val ?>, $val is a php variable name

Comment: how $val will know that I want to receive value-id

Comment: could please provide more details about your question?

Comment: Inside the modal I would like to create a Variable exemple $myvar = "the value id from the html";

Comment: Are you creating the modal content dynamically? As in via AJAX? I'm confused as to how PHP could be involved at all. If this is purely a client-side event, seems like js might be a more useful tool.

Comment: No the modal is not create dynamical. A simple example of what i'm trying to do is : an href with a value inside that trigger a modal with a php code inside that echo the value.

Answer (score 1):

Call a ajax function on onclick like this :-

```
<a value-id='1' href='#myModal' class='marker' title='Edit'  onclick="functionname(passifvalueisdynamichere)">LINK</a>
```

Now if required get value from server side then you can call like :-

```
  function functionname(id) {
        xmlhttp = getobject();
        var query = "id="+id+"&action=setdraftMessage";
        var base_url = document.getElementById("baseurlval").value;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                var newArray = new Array();
                      ////get value from server side///////////////
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                ///setvalue like///
document.getElementById("mailid").value =newArray[0];

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", base_url + "index.php/pass/index?type=setdraftMessage&"+ query, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client-side language and PHP is a server-side language. You cannot run PHP code inside your JavaScript.

If you want to populate data in the modal and send it to the back-end, submit a form to a PHP script on your server.

Don't use an `<input type="submit" />` inside of your modal. It will not play nicely with Bootstrap. Use a link to submit the form via Ajax. You can style the link as a Bootstrap button.

For Example, if the link has a class of submit and the form has an ID of 'my-form' you can do the following in jQuery to submit the form:

```
$(function() {
     $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.submit', function() {
         var form = $('#my-form');
         var data = form.serialize(); 
         var url = form.attr('action');
         $.post(url, data)
             .done(function() {
                 alert('thanks for submitting your form!')
             })
             .fail(function() {
                 alert('uh oh, something went wrong! PLease try again');
             })
     });

 });
```

Obviously you'll have to write a PHP script to handle the form.